# R: RGraphviz installation

Tags: r, installation, graphviz

I've been trying to install the library using brute force - trying different combinations of the things people have posted in mailing lists (I'm too lazy to list them out one by one, but I think I tried the most of them. I can list that too if it helps anyone.). The results have varied from a harmless message of a missing dll to RGui not being able to start before I remove the library manually. Nevertheless, I haven't succeeded...

Do you know how to install it properly, so that it works? I'm running 64bit Windows 7 and I'm not keen of compiling packages from source. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this tone is really justified. Why is it wrong for him to seek out if someone else has already solved this problem and can lay out the steps? I think you are reading an implied criticism of CRAN that the OP did not make.

Comment: +1 Dirk for VirtualBox+Ubuntu combo. I use it sometimes to check differences between Windows/Linux behaviour of R.

Comment: Dirk's comment leaves me speechless and makes me feel that he took my question very personally (I have no idea of why). I also don't know what's wrong about finding out if someone else has figured this out earlier and I guess that's what this site is all about. For your information, before posting, I did everything I could and within my skillset to make the install work. After hours of work I still hadn't figured it out and that's why I asked it here. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

**Install Rgraphviz 2.2.1 from Bioconductor**

According to the latest [README](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/readmes/Rgraphviz/README):

> Rgraphviz now comes bundles with Graphviz.  This should greatly simplify
>   installation on all platforms, compared with earlier versions.

Bioconductor 2.11 contains a lot of libraries that you might not want or need, but it does seem to be the easiest path to achieving what you want. These are the instructions on the [Rgraphviz homepage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html):

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rgraphviz")
```

These instructions work for R x64 2.15.2 on Windows 7

```
library("Rgraphviz")
```

Loading required package: graph
Loading required package: grid

```
set.seed(123)
V <- letters[1:10]
M <- 1:4
g1 <- randomGraph(V, M, 0.2)
plot(g1)
```

[image: Rgraphviz demo]

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 12.04. >No package 'libgvc' found
I've tried editing the path, and it then complains about a make failure.

Answer (score 2):

The README inside the *source package* for RGraphviz contains very some pretty clear instructions.

I think it's a bit user-unfriendly to those who only want to install the binary package, to hint that they might also want to download and unpack a tar.gz file containing the complete source, in order to find some technical info .... which turns out to be absolutely crucial.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problems to install Rgraphviz (for using it in Bayesian Network packages). I used to get brute force solutions, but, now I trying an other one described [here in this page](http://rhugin.r-forge.r-project.org/)

maybe you had also tried. If you succeed in installing Rgraphviz, I will be grateful if you learn me how to do.

Answer (score 1):

One word of warning.  If you follow the installation instructions for Rgrahpviz precisely, things won't work.  Installing the package graphviz edits the environment `PATH`, but incorrectly. I didn't notice and I bet lots of others missed it too.

Rgraphviz wants to look for the binary in `...;C:\Graphviz2.20\bin\;` 
BUT the graphviz install adds a path only as far as `;C:\Graphviz2.20\;`.

You'll have to edit it. Older instructions suggest a manual edit anyway, but newer ones leave it to graphviz.

Answer (score 1):

Since with the version of R 3.6.1 the script http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R returns this message " Error: With R version 3.5 or greater, install Bioconductor packages using BiocManager; see https://bioconductor.org/install " I solved the problem with the following steps:

1. Get the list of directories used by R to install libraries and
   choose the one with write permissions using: `.libPaths()`
2. Installing the "BiocManager" library using: `install.packages("BiocManager")`
3. Installation of the library "bioconductor" by forcing the directory
   with write permissions using: `BiocManager::install("Rgraphviz", lib = "C:/Users/tizbet/Documents/R/win-library/3.6")`

I worked on the following R installation:

`platform x86_64-w64-mingw32`, `arch x86_64`, `os mingw32`, `system x86_64, mingw32`, `version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)`

Answer (score 0):

I am using R-Studio on Ubuntu 12.10 x64 and installed Rgraphviz from the BioC software repository. Hope this helps. Eg: http://www.biotricks.net/2012/03/rstudio-and-bioconductor.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have managed to solve your problem 100% but my installation problem came with the R version. Rgraphiz is developed by Bioconductor and it seems to be outdated. However, I had to use it since I moved to a new company and they are using it in one of their shiny apps for whatever reason.

With that being said, I have a dirty solve that I came up with after a couple of days of struggling with it.

- First I include a line in the code which seems to be needed since without that line the shiny app simply doesn't do anything after opening:

  if(!requireNamespace('BiocManager', quietly = TRUE)) 
  install.packages('BiocManager')

It's weird that it won't work otherwise.The above line is found on Bioconductor's site: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html

- The second thing you need to do only once is to run the biocLite command below in the R console to install the Rgraphviz package

  source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
  biocLite("Rgraphviz")

The above command I found on another thread: [R: RGraphviz installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070314/r-rgraphviz-installation)

Hopefully this update will help you or anyone else.